# What's wrong with this Ajax code

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

This javascript code run without problem in chrome and IE but have a problem in firefox, i need to know what's wrong?

```
    <script>
function checkGurantee() {
var gurantee = document.getElementById('gurantee_no').value;
if (gurantee === '') {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
return;
}
var params = "gurantee_no=" + gurantee;
request = new ajaxRequest();
request.open("POST", "check_gurantee.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
if (this.status === 200) {
if (this.responseText != null) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
else alert("Ajax error: No data received");
}
else alert( "Ajax error: " + this.statusText);
}
}
request.send(params);
}
function ajaxRequest() {
try{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(e1) {
try{
request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e2) {
try{
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e3) {
request = false;
}
}
}
return request;
}
</script>
```

And this is HTML part:

```
    <section class="form">
<form action="javascript:void()" method="POST" class="formstyle1">
    <label for="gurantee">لطفاً شماره گارانتی را وارد نمایید:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="gurantee_no" id="gurantee_no" class="textfield" />
    <input type="button" value="جستجو" class="btn" onClick="checkGurantee()" />
    <span id='info'></span>
</form>         
        </section>
```

Comment: wha do you mean by "but have a problem in firefox and IE", do you have a syntax error ? execution error ? security ? please give as much details as you can.

Comment: This problem solved successfully, tnxX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your if check is not correct it should be

```
if (gurantee == '')
{
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = ''
return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is syntactically incorrect.

- There are no semi-colons (i.e. `;`) inserted anywhere in the code, which means you will get unexpected results. You should add a semi-colon at the end of every line in JavaScript.
- The opening braces have to be on the same line, not in next line.
- For comparison operators, instead of equality (i.e. `==`), use the [Identity / strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=test#Identity_strict_equality_()) (i.e. `===`) operator in order to avoid type conversion in the comparison.

Fix these errors before proceeding.

Comment: To add to what @Gaurish has said. every time you create something new you should use the var keyword too. i,e `params = "` should become `var params = "`.

Comment: Thanks, i apply all of your notice and edit my code but still have problem, may you check again

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this purpose... 
With jQuery your code will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('form').bind('submit', function(event) {
            var form = $(this),
                data = form.serializeArray();

            $.post(form.attr('action'), data, function(request) {
                $('#info').html(request);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And your `section`:

```
<section class="form">
    <form action="check_gurantee.php" class="formstyle1">
        <label for="gurantee">لطفاً شماره گارانتی را وارد نمایید:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="gurantee_no" class="textfield" />
        <input type="submit" value="جستجو" class="btn" />
        <span id='info'></span>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, i apply your notice and edit my code but still have problem, may you check again

Answer (score 0):

This code needs some major love. You do not have a single semi-colon in your entire paste block, and the JavaScript parser automatically adds these to end of lines, which means every line that does not have an opening brace (none of them) is going to be terminated.

1. end your statements with semicolons
2. properly indent your code
3. put your opening braces on the proper line
4. re-post (or edit) if you still have problems

:)

Comment: Thanks, i apply all of your notice and edit my code but still have problem, may you check again